# Solr query to Postman's raw data query

Tags: solr, postman

This is my Solr query: qt section: /select
q section: -*nest_path*:*
fl section: *, [child limit=-1]

[Solr query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8MKPU.png)

and I wanna convert this to Postman's form-data like " stmt:  select `id`,`title` from TABLE_NAME where `author_code` is not null limit 100 " to reach same result.

Comment: We’d love to help you, but your question lacks information and clarity. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

If you execute your query from the Solr Admin web page you should see the corresponding URL that you will need for Postman at the top of the page

In this case the URL will be:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/puldata/select?fl=*%2C%20%5Bchild%20limit%3D-1%5D&q=-nest_path%3A*
```

I am not sure your query is valid, though. But that would be a different issue.

[image]